# node(int index) in LinkedList

Tags: java, collections, linked-list, bit-manipulation

Can someone explain me the logic of method node(int index) in LinkedList. What gives the bit offset by 1 :

```
(index < (size >> 1))
```

Method:

```
Node<E> node(int index) {

    if `(index < (size >> 1)) {
        Node<E> x = first;
        for (int i = 0; i < index; i++)
            x = x.next;
        return x;
    } else {
        Node<E> x = last;
        for (int i = size - 1; i > index; i--)
            x = x.prev;
        return x;
    }
}
```

Thanks for answers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`size >> 1` is equivalent to `size / 2`

I guess this function find the `node` at index `x`.

Basically, what it does is compare `index` with total number of nodes.

If `index < size/2` then it searches from `0` to `size/2`

If `index > size/2` then it searches from `size` to `size/2`

So for example, if you do not compare `index` with `size/2`, you may have loop over entire list, which is `O(n)`. By doing this, you can reduce the iteration by half. (`O(n/2)`)